# UIPageViewController - Change page programmatically doesn't work on iPhone 4s/5/5s

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I have an App for both iPad/iPhone and it perfectly runs on all of them and for all version but iPhone 4S, 5 and 5s.

I have a UIPageViewController with WebViews as cells.
I have another simple UICollectionView used as page selector: its function is let the user to jump to the Xth page selected.

My code is very simple: I pass the index of the cell touched to the UIPageViewController for apply my "slideToPage(index)" function.

For iPhone 4S/5/5S, when the animation is completed, it instantly returns to the old page, so the user can't jump page and he can only turn the pages one at time:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
func slideToPage(index: Int, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    let currentViewController = pageViewController?.viewControllers![0] as! WebViewViewController
    let count = dataSource.controllers.count
    let currentPageIndex = dataSource.controllers.indexOf(currentViewController)!

    guard index < count else { return }

    // Moving forward
    if index > currentPageIndex {
        if let vc: WebViewViewController = dataSource.controllers[index] {
            self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers([vc], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: {
                void in
                vc.loadContent()
            })
        }
    }
    // Moving backward
    else if index < currentPageIndex {
        if let vc: WebViewViewController = dataSource.controllers[index] {
            self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers([vc], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Reverse, animated: true, completion: {
                void in
                vc.loadContent()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The problem is in the animation. If a set animation:false inside the setViewControllers() function, the pageview goes to the correct view.
If true, at the end of the animation, the pageview turn to the previous page.

Comment: what os runs on those devices? all same?

Comment: yeah, all the same (9.3). Even in the simulator (not only physical device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some try, for the moment I solved setting **false** the animation parameter inside `self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers()`.
Seems to be an iOS bug.

So, I added a *isAnimated:bool* var for use the animation only for iPad devices; here's my update:

```
func slideToPage(index: Int, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    if index >= dataSource.controllers.count || index < 0 {
        return
    }

    let currentViewController = pageViewController?.viewControllers![0] as! WebViewViewController
    let currentPageIndex = dataSource.controllers.indexOf(currentViewController)!
    let isAnimated = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)

    // Moving forward
    if index > currentPageIndex {
        if let vc: WebViewViewController = dataSource.controllers[index] {
            self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers([vc], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: isAnimated, completion: { complete in
                vc.loadContent()
            })
        }
    }
    // Moving backward
    else if index < currentPageIndex {
        if let vc: WebViewViewController = dataSource.controllers[index] {
            self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers([vc], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Reverse, animated: isAnimated, completion: { complete in
                vc.loadContent()
            })
        }
    }
}
```